# Javascript to manipulate css files?

Tags: javascript

Im using javascript to change the display of a object, there is a css class already for the same object : #id{display:none;}    When i use javascript to alter display to  display:block, the Display:block; appears on the object itself in the HTML. The css propertys seem to be overriding the html's propertys because it still doesnt display. 

        prev4.onclick = function(){
    lrg.setAttribute("src", eventpic4);
    lefta.setAttribute("display", "block");
        };

Comment: post some codes what you've tried

Comment: HTML inline styles will always take precedence over CSS styles. I recommend opening it up in Chrome's Web Developer and see what the computed styles are for the element.

Comment: @Alan unless the css style has !important. Also, there are some quirks between using actual css and html style attributes(like with and border attributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good practice is to avoid manipulating styles directly in JavaScript; you can rely on classes instead and let CSS handle the styling:

```
<style>
  #id { display: none; }
  #id.enabled { display: block; }
</style>
<script>
  document.getElementById("id").className = "enabled";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 document.getElementById('id').style.display = 'block'
```